# django using ajax in wistia

Tags: ajax, django, wistia

I build my django app to get watch video time.

I reveive data from wistiaApi and comfirm the video time from alert.

I comfirm the send signal when video_time='10' instead video_time = reuqest.POST.get('video_time'), but using ajax, there are no success message. Where is problem?

**view**

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        video_view.send(
             request.user,
             video_time=request.POST.get('video_time'),
             primary_obj_video=obj,
             secondary_obj_video=cat
        )
```

**template**

```
wistiaEmbed = jQuery(".wistia_embed")[0].wistiaApi;

var time = wistiaEmbed.duration();

alert(time);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {video_time: time},
    success: function(){
        alert ("hi");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url` is missing inside `ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/your_url/', #<-----------------
   type: "POST",
   data: {video_time: time},
   success: function(){
    alert ("hi");
   }
});
```